# System.out.println not printing to console

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly

I have a Spring web app running on Wildfly 8.* and for some reason it won't print to the console. I see all the console logs and stack traces fine but the System messages just don't appear.

The problem might be with my log4j setup so I'll post that config;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration  PUBLIC
  "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

I've ran apps on JBoss 7.1 before however without this problem so I'm really at a loss on what could be wrong.

Feel free to ask about any of my other config not sure what would be needed.

Edit:

```
logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG
logger.org.jboss.as.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.jacorb.config.level=ERROR
logger.jacorb.config.useParentHandlers=true

logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.level=WARN
logger.org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.useParentHandlers=true

logger.com.arjuna.level=WARN
logger.com.arjuna.useParentHandlers=true

handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.level=INFO
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=COLOR-PATTERN
handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush,target,enabled
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.target=SYSTEM_OUT
handler.CONSOLE.enabled=true

handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=ALL
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
handler.FILE.properties=append,autoFlush,enabled,suffix,fileName
handler.FILE.constructorProperties=fileName,append
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.enabled=true
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.fileName=C\:\\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\\standalone\\log\\server.log

formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n

formatter.COLOR-PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.properties=pattern
formatter.COLOR-PATTERN.pattern=%K{level}%d{HH\:mm\:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n
```

Here is my logging config in my standalone deployments folder.

Comment: Have you consider the level DEBUG is open for printing

Comment: Have a look at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-478

Comment: This seems exactly like the issue I was having. I will try and re-add log4j to my project and see if this solves it. If it does you should make it an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: hey look at my question here it's about logging on wildfly thanks : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59006162/7149835

Answer (score 3):

I had a log4j.properties file at the root level of the .war (WEB-INF/classes) from years ago that caused the same issue - deletion fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a logging framework, there are 2 ways to fix it:

1. Remove the logging framework and all the configuration files (why would I do that)
2. Move your `log4j.properties` file from `src/main/resources` to `WEB-INF` folder.

Quoting: [JBoss Docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration), Section 'Per Deployment Logging'

> Per-deployment logging allows you to add a logging configuration file to your deployment and have the logging for that deployment configured according to the configuration file. In an EAR the configuration should be in the META-INF directory. In a WAR or JAR deployment the configuration file can be in either the META-INF or WEB-INF/classes directories.
> The following configuration files are allowed:
>
> - logging.properties
> - jboss-logging.properties
> - log4j.properties
> - log4j.xml
> - jboss-log4j.xml

Answer (score 0):

I usually have trouble configuring logs per deployment in wildfly, but you can use the logging system from wildfly, changing logging configuration of your standalone ou domain config files to this would do the trick:

```
<root-logger>
    <level name="TRACE"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
        <handler name="FILE"/>
    </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

Comment: Hi I added my standalone config file for logging. Not sure where this would be defined although I assume it can be in .xml or .properties

Comment: Are you using wildfly? the standalone should be i xml located in wildfly/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml or wildfly/domain/configuration/standalone.xml

Comment: What you suggested was already in my standalone. I have fixed the issue by completely removing log4j from my project as well as removing the dependencies. The issue was probably config there.