# Loggers and printers ignored in SpringMVC web application deployed in wildfly

Tags: java, spring-mvc, logging, wildfly

I have a weird, embarrassing issue with my spring MVC project, don't know how solve it.

I have a class called **FrontController** that plays the role of a **SpringMVC** controller, All the methods works fine with no problem but one, at **Runtime** when it's deployed on widlfly instance, all the **Loggers** that i put, all **Sysouts** are totally ignored. i put some breakpoints in order to detect whether it's a problem, everything **100** over **100**.

Down below the code that i was trying to test.

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/buyForm")
    public class FrontController {

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FrontController.class);

        @Autowired
        private IAppService appService;

        /**
         * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/completeTransaction/{id}", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
        public String home(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long merchantCode,
                @RequestParam(required = false) String transactionAmount,
                @RequestParam(required = false) String articlesNumber, @RequestParam(required = false) String randomVar) {

            App app = appService.findApp(merchantCode);
            if (app == null) {
                return "not_allowed";
            }

            model.addAttribute("transactionAmount", transactionAmount);
            model.addAttribute("articlesNumber", articlesNumber);
            model.addAttribute("randomVar", randomVar);

            // This the portion ignored at runtime. no values, no messages printed
            System.out.println(" --------------- "+transactionAmount);
            System.out.println(" --------------- "+articlesNumber);
            System.out.println(" --------------- "+randomVar);

            return "buyForm";
        }

        /**
         * @return
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/notAllowed")
        public String notAllowed() {
            return "not_allowed";
        }
    }
```

**PS: The printers work fine when they're invoked from main method**

Comment: How are you testing this?

Comment: I invoke the controller by sending a POST request to my method from another web app deployed on the same server.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840406/system-out-println-not-printing-to-console

Comment: @SoufianeRabii have you tried using System.out.print in an other method, is this problem only for this controller or in any other controller>?

Comment: now i have found the problem cause, it's a wildfly 8.2 but i still can't find a way out.

Comment: have you configured the loggers in the profile ?

Comment: I don't configuring profil means, i solved the problem but at the same i created another one, i remove log4j.xml existing in resources folder, then jboss started printing all the reuqired info. But the loggers were disabled in  log in main context